# Inconsistent Creation and Update Dates in Angular Project when Sending to ASP.NET Core 7 Web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I am encountering an issue with the creation and update dates in my Angular project when sending data to an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API.

Although most of the time the dates are being sent correctly in the `POST` and `PUT` methods, occasionally I am experiencing a problem where the created date is not reflecting the actual recent date. Also, I am sending that date's using TypeScript like this:

```
const createdDate: Date = new Date();
```

I have tried to change some API methods in my Angular project, but all of them did not help.

Comment: There might be a Date object on the API as well, have you checked it? If not then please post the error and the code on API side as well.

Comment: This is hard to know without providing a minimal, reproducible example, way to reproduce. How do you declare the `createdDate` variable, and in which scope (global/local)? For example, if in the global scope for the component, the variable is defined and assigned with the Date value during the creation of component. So that could be possible that the user (stay) opens the page for a few days and submit, this could make the submitted date is not the latest date.

Comment: From what I work on, I will set the creation/updated date on the API side instead of passing from the front end. Thus, the dates will be followed on the system timezone/UTC (if using `DateTime.UtcNow`). Didn't say submitting from the front end is not a bad way, but you need to take note that the dates sent are according to the browser timezone.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might relate the time zone on client side and server side, when create or update the date, try to use the following code to create the UTC date.

```
const utcdate = new Date((new Date()).toUTCString())
```

Then when display the date, you can use the `ToString()` method to display the UTC date as the local date.

Refer to the following sample code:

```
const event = new Date();
console.log(event.toString());  // Expected output: "Wed Jul 12 2023 10:21:25 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)"
console.log(event.toUTCString()); // Expected output: "Wed, 12 Jul 2023 02:21:25 GMT"

const event2 = new Date(event.toUTCString());
console.log(event2.toUTCString()); // Expected output: "Wed, 12 Jul 2023 02:21:25 GMTT"

const utcdate = new Date((new Date()).toUTCString());
console.log(utcdate.toUTCString()); // Expected output: "Wed, 12 Jul 2023 02:21:25 GMT"
console.log(utcdate); // Expected output: "Wed Jul 12 2023 10:21:25 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)"
```

The result like this:

[image]